# Do you know why the login is not working? (The urls are defined in the basic settings)

Tags: facebook

I have a link for the user to login using facebook:

```
<a href="{{route('social.auth',
['provider' => 'facebook'])}}" > 
<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login with Facebook</a>
```

When the user clicks in "Login with facebook" it shows:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and
>   Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth
>   Redirect URIs.

In facebook basic settings:

App Domains:

```
https://....ngrok.io
```

Site URL:

```
https://....ngrok.io/auth/facebook/callback
```

In .env file:

```
APP_URL=https://....ngrok.io
```

Routes:

```
Auth::routes();



Route::get('auth/{provider}', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as' => 'social.auth'
]);

Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@handleProviderCallback',
]);
```

When the user clicks in the login button and appears that error he is redirected to "https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...proj.test...facebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=...". There is "proj.test" that is the url to access the project in localhost I dont know why it appears there if in the basic and advanced settings are only defined the ngrok.io url´s.

Comment: You might have to add your website URI under Advanced settings related to whitelisted origins. Try that. (P.S. bug is not related to `php`, `laravel` etc. but `facebook` developer settings specifically)

Comment: In "Share Redirect Domain Whitelist
"?

Comment: Maybe "Server IP Whitelist" that mentions _App requests using the app secret must originate from these IP addresses._

Comment: Thanks, now the error change to "Unable to load URL: The domain of this URL is not included in the application domains. In order to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app's settings.
".

Comment: Does your App Domain input field contain `http/https`? It's only supposed to contain the domain name, for example, `ngrok.io`.

Comment: Its only ...ngork.io.

Comment: When the user clicks in the login button and appears that error he is redirected to "https://www.facebook.com/v3.0/dialog/oauth?client_id=...&redirect_uri=...proj.test...facebook%2Fcallback&scope=email&response_type=code&state=...". There is "proj.test" that is the url to access the project in localhost I dont know why it appears there if in the basic and advanced settings are only defined the ngrok.io url´s.

Comment: Because it’s your code on your server that creates this URL, it does not go and check what settings you made in the app dashboard first ... So if you are calling this via `proj.test`, then it likely sees that as the base URI to use to build absolute URLs. Use your `ngrok.io` address to access this in your browser to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, but Im using the ngork.io url to access the login page that has the login with facebook button.

Comment: Then check if you have a “base URL” or something like that configured anywhere in your settings (of your local app/code I mean, not in the Facebook app dashboard) ... your app must get that part of the URL it creates from _somewhere_ …

Comment: Thanks, do you know in which files is necessary to check? I already change in the .env file but sam error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in the localhost with the "proj.test" URL? If yes, add `proj.test` & `localhost` under **App Domains**. If that doesn't work, try adding them in **Server IP Whitelist**.

I didn't know that you were testing on localhost. I'm pretty sure that this is why you're getting that error.

Comment: Thanks, but Im using the ngork.io url to access the login page that has the login with facebook button. Im not accessing the login page using the "proj.test" url.